# How to detect change of Chrome Tab in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, google-chrome

How to detect change of Chrome Tab in Flutter Web.
I've been searching but couldn't find any thing related.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will need an eventListener like this one:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", (event) => {
  if (document.visibilityState == "visible") {
    console.log("tab is active")
  } else {
    console.log("tab is inactive")
  }
});
```

And inside your Dart Code you have to listen to the changes

[Flutter (Web) how to listen to javascript event or pass javascript data to flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62251488/flutter-web-how-to-listen-to-javascript-event-or-pass-javascript-data-to-flutt)